# jQuery: Handling cross domain jsonp bad request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, jsonp

I am unable to catch a bad request error with my jquery code.

```
$.get('http://example.com/', {}, function () {}, 'jsonp')
 .done(function () {
   // never fires
 })
 .fail(function () {
   // never fires
 })
 .always(function () {
   // never fires
 });
```

I just get the error

> GET http://example.com?callback=jQuery17102424617672804743_1366109250123&_=1366111087274 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you tried to open that link in browser and see the result? Does it show right data?

Comment: It shows my web host's 404 page which is what I expect. I want to catch for this 404 page when if my application ever goes down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `.get` to call other domain. You need to make **jsonp** call with `.ajax`.

but it will be not enough to get error. Also you need to specify `timout` attribute. without it you **will not** get error.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://hq.am/asdasdasdasd?callback=?',
  timeout: 3000,
  dataType: "json",
  error: function(data){
      alert('error');
  }
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/wJcMy/)

Comment: Yes adding the timeout property did the trick. Thanks. (This also fires the fail() callback)